# Web Socket using Java spring boot

Tags: spring, postman, spring-websocket

Hi stack overflow family,
I am a beginner in web socket using java spring boot. I have followed some tutorials about it but I am facing issue to test it on postman.
I am not getting that how to test it on postman like what will be the endpoint.

I wanted to get any assistance or tutorial which will help me to test this thing on postman.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Start by modifying the http request to websocket in postman,In SpringBoot server ,If you configure `@ServerEndpoint(value = "/test")` ,So postman should be filled with `ws://localhost:port/test`